# Best loop to remove children with bottom-up deletion in a treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView organized as:

```
Level1
   level 1.1
     level 1.1.1
     level 1.1.2
     level 1.1.3
       level 1.1.3.1
       level 1.1.3.2
   level 1.2
   level 1.3
level2
   level 2.1

 .............
```

Each level is a ViewModel that inherits from TreeViewModelBase.

Given a viewmodel of say level 1.1.3.2, this code will remove it from the TreeView:

```
var y = SelectedItem as TreeViewModelBase;
var z = y.Parent;

z.Children.Remove(y);

if (z.Children.Count == 0)
{
    var g = z.Parent;
    g.Children.Remove(z);
}
```

What would be a single loop that starts from the selected item and remove it from its parent. If the parent no longer has any children, then remove the parent from its parent and likewise work up the tree structure.

What is the best looping construct to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

- an item model that can be constructed with a friendly syntax (no need to set its parent)
- a pruning tool that will remove an item and cleanup the hierarchy as much as it can

### Example

(pruning item 1.4.1.1)

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

### Objects:

`Item` : your item

- it watches for childrens you add to it and (un)sets its `Parent` property
- provides `Prune` method which removes it from its parent, climbs up and repeat until not possible

Code:

```
internal class Item
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)] private ItemCollection _children;

    public Item()
    {
        Children = new ItemCollection();
    }

    public Item Parent { get; private set; }

    public ItemCollection Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set
        {
            if (_children != null)
            {
                _children.CollectionChanged -= Children_CollectionChanged;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                value.CollectionChanged += Children_CollectionChanged;
                // Notify about previously (never notified) added items 
                if (value.Count > 0)
                {
                    value.RaiseCollectionChanged(
                        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, value));
                }
            }

            _children = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private void Children_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<Item> newItems = e.NewItems.OfType<Item>();
                foreach (Item item in newItems)
                {
                    item.Parent = this;
                }
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<Item> oldItems = e.OldItems.OfType<Item>();
                foreach (Item item in oldItems)
                {
                    item.Parent = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", Name);
    }

    public void Prune()
    {
        Item parent = Parent;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.Children.Remove(this);


            while (parent.Children.Count <= 0)
            {
                Item grandParent = parent.Parent;
                if (grandParent != null)
                {
                    grandParent.Children.Remove(parent);
                    parent = grandParent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ItemCollection` :

a collection of items using `ObservableCollection`, very useful in alleviating the need to specify parent as you will see on the example below.

```
internal class ItemCollection : ObservableCollection<Item>
{
    public ItemCollection()
    {
    }

    public ItemCollection(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    internal void RaiseCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }
}
```

**Demo code**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var root = new Item
        {
            Name = "root",
            Children = new ItemCollection(new[]
            {
                new Item
                {
                    Name = "item1.1",
                    Children = new ItemCollection(new[]
                    {
                        new Item {Name = "item1.1.1"},
                        new Item {Name = "item1.1.2"}
                    })
                },
                new Item
                {
                    Name = "item1.2",
                    Children = new ItemCollection(new[]
                    {
                        new Item {Name = "item1.2.1"}
                    })
                },
                new Item {Name = "item1.3"}
            })
        };

        var item1411 = new Item
        {
            Name = "item1.4.1.1"
        };
        var item141 = new Item
        {
            Name = "item1.4.1",
            Children = new ItemCollection(new[]
            {
                item1411
            })
        };
        var item14 = new Item
        {
            Name = "item1.4",
            Children = new ItemCollection(new[]
            {
                item141
            })
        };
        root.Children.Add(item14);

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        Console.WriteLine("before pruning");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        PrintHierarchy(root);

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        Console.WriteLine("after pruning");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        item1411.Prune();
        PrintHierarchy(root);

        DataContext = root;
    }

    private void PrintHierarchy(Item root, int level = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", level)), root);

        if (root.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Item child in root.Children)
            {
                PrintHierarchy(child, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding (wpfApplication3:Item.Children)}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="wpfApplication3:Item" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT**

The system will obviously reflect changes in the tree such as if you do :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _item1411.Prune();
}
```

The `TreeView` will be updated seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Aybe's answer. In my specific case where all the ViewModel's are held within ObservableCollections, and all derive from the same TreeViewModelBase, the below code seems much simplier. The TreeView will automatically be updated.

```
  var z = SelectedItem as TreeViewModelBase;

   TreeViewModelBase y;
                        do
                        {
                            y = z;

                            if (y.Parent == null) break;
                            z = y.Parent;
                            z.Children.Remove(y);

                        } while(z.Children.Count==0);
```